# Web service to add a phone number with SMS validation

Tags: beginner, validation, authentication, clojure, web-services

I'm new to Clojure. How can I make this more idiomatic Clojure code? Among other things, there are three (do) blocks and I don't think using (def) as many times as I do is a recommended idea.

```
(defn add-phone
  "Add a phone number to a given service. There are a few steps we have to take:
    - Validate the service name and token
    - Validate the phone number 
    - Send a text message to the number
    - Store the number in the database
  Arguments:
    request - an authorized HTTP request
  Returns:
    201 Resource Created - phone number added to a service
    400 Bad Request - invalid phone number or bad request"
  [request auth-type]
  (do
    (println "Url requested is " (:request-method request) " " (:uri request))
    (println request)
    (def auth-header ((:headers request) "authorization"))
    (def auth-map (utils/get-auth-header auth-type auth-header))
    (if (model/invalid-user-and-pass auth-map auth-type)
        {:status 401,
         :headers {"WWW-Authenticate" "Basic realm=\"smsauth.herokuapp.com\""}}
      (do
        (def raw-phone-no (:phone_number (:params request)))
        (def service-name (:service-name auth-map))
        (if raw-phone-no
          (do 
            (def valid-phone-no (utils/parse-phone-no raw-phone-no))
            ; XXX get the service id some other way.
            (def service-map (model/service-in-db service-name))
            (def service-id (service-map :id))
            ; XXX check that service doesn't already have phone number
            (model/store-phone-no :numbers service-id valid-phone-no)
            (twilio/send-sms-verify twilio/sms-url valid-phone-no service-name)
            ; XXX jsonify this, send more information, document it.
            {:status 201,
             :body (json/json-str {
                      :service_name service-name,
                      :phone_number valid-phone-no,
                      :status "active",
                      :uri (:uri request)
                      ; should have some kind of unique id for the phone number
                      ; here.
                      ; also return the date
                    })})
          {:status 400,
            :body (json/json-str {:error "Please include a phone_number."})})))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several errors/bad styles here:

- First do isn't necessary, as body of function can contain several expressions
- instead of `def` inside function it's better to use `let` that allows to "define" several variables in one step, and they will visible only inside this `let` block. So 2nd & 3rd `do` could be replaced with corresponding `let`
- if variable is used only once, then you can include function call directly into map

So your code will look like:

```
(defn add-phone
  [request auth-type]
  (println "Url requested is " (:request-method request) " " (:uri request))
  (println request)
  (let [auth-header ((:headers request) "authorization")
        auth-map (utils/get-auth-header auth-type auth-header)]
    (if (model/invalid-user-and-pass auth-map auth-type)
      {:status 401,
       :headers {"WWW-Authenticate" "Basic realm=\"smsauth.herokuapp.com\""}}
      (let [raw-phone-no (:phone_number (:params request))
            service-name (:service-name auth-map)]
        (if raw-phone-no
          (let [valid-phone-no (utils/parse-phone-no raw-phone-no) ; XXX get the service id some other way.
                service-map (model/service-in-db service-name)
                service-id (service-map :id) ; XXX check that service doesn't already have phone number
                ]
            (model/store-phone-no :numbers service-id valid-phone-no)
            (twilio/send-sms-verify twilio/sms-url valid-phone-no service-name)
                                        ; XXX jsonify this, send more information, document it.
            {:status 201,
             :body (json/json-str {
                                   :service_name service-name,
                                   :phone_number valid-phone-no,
                                   :status "active",
                                   :uri (:uri request)
                                        ; should have some kind of unique id for the phone number
                                        ; here.
                                        ; also return the date
                                   })})
          {:status 400,
           :body (json/json-str {:error "Please include a phone_number."})})))))
```

P.S. it's also good idea to check value of `service-map` - if it will `nil`, then you'll get NPE. So instead of `(service-map :id)` you can write `(:id service-map)` that will correctly work if `service-map` will `nil`...